# Do GTA 5 saves back-up to a cloud service?

Tags: pc, grand-theft-auto-v

For GTA 5 (on PC), if I have a save file, will it automatically back-up to either the Steam or Rockstar cloud, or do I have to save it manually? If it have to save it manually, will you please provide the default directory for saves?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The save files do **not** get backed up to cloud services, on steam or on RGSC versions of the game, you have to backup and restore them yourself.

The save files are located in `C:\Users\USERNAME-HERE\Documents\Rockstar Games\GTA V\Profiles`.

Answer (score 1):

Since [August 3, 2017](https://support.rockstargames.com/articles/225410988/GTAV-PC-Cloud-Saves), Story Mode Saved Games can be backed up to the Rockstar Cloud. This option can be disabled from the Rockstar Game Launcher settings in a per-game basis:

[image]